# Using jquery to make enormous number of posts to a page

Tags: jquery, post

Using the following code, I need to post some data to script.  I know this isn't ideal, but it's a one off operation to save some data which got waylaid.

So, the question is, how do you best reccommend posting this data so as to cause minimum server problems?

Thanks in advance

```
<script>
    $.post("path/path/callback.php", { "key":"value", "key2":"value2"});
    $.post("path/path/callback.php", { "key":"value", "key2":"value2"});
    $.post("path/path/callback.php", { "key":"value", "key2":"value2"});
    // etc etc x 300+
</script>
```

Comment: With 300+ $.posts minimum = huge, especially for the browser

Answer (score 0):

Don't post it via your website.

If you have access to the database in which this will be stored write some queries to create the data, or import it in.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the server specs and configuration, and how and what is implemented in your callback.php. If your "service" was designed to manage the load of 300+ users, for example, then your code should be fine for a one off deal. However, there are many ways to do such migration, including altering you callback.php file or using server side another scripting language to handle this, and of course, inserting your data directly into the database.